# CUDA negative array index test

Tags: cuda, pycuda

As it's possible in C to index a negative array location and go out of the array bounds this code compiles and "works".

```
__global__ void do_something_bad(int * in_a){
   in_a[-1] = 666; // assign a value to an out of bounds memory location
}
```

My assumption is the above code is doing the following (please let me know if this assumption is wrong):

```
GPU memory before:
[0x00 = usually unused memory][0x01= Start of in_a][0x02 = in_a] ....
GPU memory after:
[0x00 = 666][0x01= Start of in_a][0x02 = in_a] ....
```

In summary the memory before the the in_a array is being set the value. This memory before in_a could contain other important data but when I'm testing it containing nothing important and thus gives me no error or failing test.

FYI: I'm using pycuda and am unit testing my code as a go.

I'm trying to avoid creating silent unpredictable errors as a result of the above. Of course in the real world example -1 would have been calculated and I've simplified the code to just the problem I want to solve.

How do I identify this error and force a detectable problem that my unit tests can pick up?

Comment: Your example is undefined behavior. Designing unit tests for UB is futile

Comment: This is a very easy error to create. How are professional teams mitigating the risk of errors as a result of this? This issue comes up in almost every array example that considers neighbor element values.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with `cuda`.  How would you answer this question in C/C++?  CUDA mostly attempts to adhere to C++.  (by the way, either valgrind - C++, or `cuda-memcheck` - CUDA C++, should be able to catch this type of error.  I don't know if that fits into your definition of unit testing or whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.)

Comment: cuda is designed for parallel operations on arrays. In C you would just have a guard statement which executes infrequently, you could do the same in cuda which I'm currently doing but given the lock step processing with 1000's of processors, feels wrong to force every thread to check its inbound when only a small number of edge cases would have issue. Not entirely sure if cuda-memcheck does the job, it might but how do you build that into the process to avoid issue?

Comment: There are completely standard design patterns to avoid the problems you are imagining without significant performance issues. Like I said, there really isn't a way to design units tests for detecting undefined behaviour, because it is undefined behaviour. Possibly static analysis might be able to detect common incorrect idioms, but even that is extremely limited, This strikes me as titling at windmills

Comment: `cuda-memcheck` doesn't provide runtime checking unless you use it at runtime.  It is not a replacement for general runtime bounds checking.  It could be useful in a unit test scenario, where the unit test specifically excited the out-of-bounds condition.  `cuda-memcheck` could tell you whether your code actually indexed out of bounds, or not.  The utility of this would depend on exactly how you constructed your unit test and the runtime bounds checking, if any.  It was not intended to be a suggestion for runtime bounds checking in the general case.  You wouldn't use valgrind there, either.

Comment: If you have a suitable method (ie. one that you know of, and like) for C++ checking of the type you desire, I would consider just implementing in CUDA C++ as well (or describe it here or on code review to get some feedback). I've seen arguments like yours ("feels wrong to force every thread to check its inbound when only a small number of edge cases would have issue") a number of times,  and I just don't buy them, unless accompanied by scientific analysis (for example, profiling demonstrating that such activity is a significant performance issue). A negative index check should cost very little

Comment: Ok, thanks guys for your help on this. Not the answer I was hoping for but makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a silent error in a kernel, I would use [assertion](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#assertion) if you're not on MacOS. Something like this:

```
#include <assert.h>

__global__ void do_something_bad(int* in_a){
  int indx;
  indx = 0; // A valid index
  assert(indx >= 0); // Lets the kernel continue
  in_a[indx] = 666;
  indx = -1; // An invalid index
  assert(indx >= 0); // Sends an error to stderr 
  in_a[indx] = 666; // This never gets executed  
}

int main(){
  int *a;
  cudaMalloc((void **)&a, 10*sizeof(int));
  do_something_bad<<<1,1>>>(a);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

However, this may affect the performance of your program. From the Programming Guide:

> Assertions are for debugging purposes. They can affect performance and
>   it is therefore recommended to disable them in production code. They
>   can be disabled at compile time by defining the NDEBUG preprocessor
>   macro before including assert.h

Comment: As an additional note, a failing assertion in kernel code corrupts the CUDA context, so in the example code given here, the failing assertion will be a detectable CUDA error returned by the runtime API at the next synchronization point.  This error is a sticky error (corrupted CUDA context), so: 1. Nothing else will be possible using CUDA in this process.  2. The data in question (e.g. `a[indx]`) will never be visible to host code, after the kernel launch.